A list of text recommendations
I've found Resource recommendations on Physics Stack Exchange which is a community effort to collect many book suggestions for many subjects in physics, and I thought it would be nice if there is one in mathematics. Any idea?

I am not sure whether you suggest something similar on [mathoverflow.se] on [math.se].
In any case, there are already many posts where you can find recommendations for books on some specific topic.
Just browse the tag textbook-recommendation on MathOverflow or book-recommendation on Mathematics.

It is worth pointing out that the question "Resource recommendations" on [physics.se] that you linked to is closed on that site. And there is a link to this discussion on their meta: Do we need/want an overarching books question?

It is not created by a community effort, but the blog "How to Become a  Pure Mathematician  (or Statistician)" might be somewhat similar to what you're looking for. It was mentioned in some posts in this network.
